# Need help making a while loop with an nested if work

Tags: python, while-loop

Here is the block of code. It goes through this code and print for example "Player 1 starts", but then it goes back to the while loop and asks me to say heads or tails again in the terminal. I do not understand why.

```
def turn_decider():
    n = 0
    print("Let's flip a coin to see who goes first!")
    sleep(1)
    while n == 0:
        coin_flip_guess = input("Heads or tails player 1? ").lower()
        heads_tails = ["heads", "tails"]
        if coin_flip_guess not in heads_tails:
            print("Say heads or tails!")
        elif coin_flip_guess in heads_tails:
            break
    mini_dic = {1: "heads", 2: "tails"}
    headsortails = mini_dic[randint(1, 2)]
    if coin_flip_guess == headsortails:
        print("Player 1 starts")
        person = "Player 1"
    elif coin_flip_guess != headsortails:
        print("Player 2 starts")
        person = "Player 2"
        return person

turn_decider()
```

Comment: It is not clear how these two code blocks are connected.

Comment: Its a function. It has no attributes but its all a function for a game of heads or tails, ultimately being part of a hangman game. The heads or tails is to see who goes first.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the code where  function is defined because if the whole is a function the indentation suggests a nested function or indentation error??

Comment: Sure let me just turn my pc on again 1 sec

Comment: okay that's edited @InhirCode, also i think i should mention, the while loop is to check that the user has typed either heads or tails and not something random.

Answer (score 0):

`return person` logically should be dedented to outside the second `elif`.

Thus `player = turn_decider()` would be a complete call. The problem of returning to the `while` loop might be because you call `turn_decider` more than once ???